# How can I change the language from VB.NET to C#.NET in VS 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio

How can I change the language from VB.NET to C#.NET in VS 2013? By default VB.NET is set as the language.

Comment: What do you mean by "**the** language"?

Comment: That is probably because you picked a VB.NET project. Start a new project, and choose one based on C#.

Answer (score 0):

*Your question is not the clearest but I assume you're taking about visual studio preferences.*

You should go over to `Tool -> Import and Export Settings`, select `Import selected environment settings` and click Next. Now you may choose to save you settings, after you do that click next and choose `Visual C#` from the tree view and click Finish.

Comment: I think you'd better go along with the recommendation of Matan Shahar. And also you can import the General Settings (the top Settings) if you want to develop applications with more programming languages, but consider to save your current settings in case of way back. So, More better than one.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that when you click New Project and select a project type, Visual Studio generates a Visual Basic .NET project while you are more interested in C#, try changing the project type:

[image: Visual Studio - New Project]