# Visual Studio Community 2013 Missing C# Add New Item

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor

I have installed Visual Studio Community 2013 but I can't add new C# items. If I right click on a folder and want to add a C# Razor cshtml file I can't, but I can add is Visual Basic vbhtml. How do I turn-on C#?

[image: Visual Basic installed but no C#?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you just pick wrong language when setup VS.

You can change it like this:

Go over to `Tool -> Import and Export Settings`, select `Import selected environment settings` and click Next. Now you may choose to save you settings, after you do that click next and choose `Visual C#` from the tree view and click Finish.

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23593723/1849444).

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something simple :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it has not helped me. Sill have missing templates in the Add -> New Item.

Comment: Hey @xmedeko did you find any solution, I am using vs2019 community with only .net core cross platform installed